# Click event on select option element is not working for all

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class= "button">
  <button id="More" type="submit">Add Parameter</button>
  <button id="Last" type="submit">Remove Parameter</button>
  <button class="Manual" id="Manual" type="submit">Manually Enter </button>
</div>
</br>
<!--WHERE USER WILL INPUT WHICH VARIABLES TO READ,-->
<form action="/output3" method="post" id="parameter" >
  <div2 id="Entire">
    <div class="fieldBlock1" id="Original">
      <fieldset style="width:215px;">
        <legend>Parameter</legend>
        <label >Parameter Name: </label>
        <select id="name"  name="name" required>
        </select> </br> </br>
        <label >Address: </label>
        <select class= "address" type=text id="address" name="address" style="width:14em;" required>
        </select> </br> </br>
        <label  >Data Size:    </label>  </br>
        <select   type=text id=sizeSelect name="size"style="width: 14em;" required>
        </select> </br> </br>
        <label >Write Data: </label> </br>
        <input  class="data" type=text id= "data" name="data" style="width: 14em;"> </input> </br></br>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div2>
```

Script-

```
  //PUTTING A CAP ON PARAMETERS TO 10, CAN CHANGE CAP
  $('#More').on('click', function(){
    if (count==11) {

    }
    else {
      //WILL APPEND THIS IF ADD PARAMETERS IS CLICKED
      $("#Entire").append("<div class='fieldBlock' id='div'><fieldset><legend>Parameter</legend><label >Parameter Name: </label><select  class= 'name' id='name'  name='name' required></select></br></br><label >Address: </label><select  class= 'address' type=text id='address'  name='address' required></select></br></br><label  >Data Size: </label> </br><select  class= 'size' type=text id='sizeSelect' name='size' required></select> </br> </br><label >Write Data: </label> </br><input  type=text id='data'  name='data' class='data' style='width: 14em;'></br></br></fieldset></div>");
      count++;
    }
  });
  if (file && file.length) {
    //FILE IS SPLIT BY COMMAS
    results = file.split(",");
    //WILL RESET OPTIONS IF NEW FILE IS UPLOADED
    $('select').children().remove();

    //ITERATE THROUGH THE FILE TO PUT PROPER PARTS IN SELECT OPTIONS
    //IF FILE IS FORMATTED DIFFERENTLY THEN THIS PART WILL HAVE TO CHANGE
    for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i=i+8) {
      if(typeof results[i+6] !== 'undefined') {
        $("select[name='name']").each(function() {
          $(this).append("<option val='"+ results[i+6] +"' address='"+ results[i] +"' sizeSelect='"+ results[i+1] +"'>" + results[i+6] + "</option>");
        });
      }
      if(typeof results[i] !== 'undefined') {
        $("select[name='address']").each(function() {
          $(this).append("<option val=''"+ results[i] +"''>" + results[i] + "</option>");
        });
      }
      if(typeof results[i+1] !== 'undefined') {
        $("select[name='size']").each(function() {
          $(this).append("<option val=''"+ results[i+1] +"''>" + results[i+1] + "</option>");
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

//TODO----- WHEN THE NAME OF PARAMETER IS CHANGED, THE ADDRESS AND SIZE SELECT IS ALSO CHANGED. DOES NOT WORK WITH APPENDED PARAMTERS..
$(function () {
  $("select[name='name']").change(function() {
      var optionSelected = $(this).find('option:selected');
      console.log($(this).val());
      $("#address").val(optionSelected.attr('address'));
      $("#size").val(optionSelected.attr('sizeSelect'));
  });
});
```

I have a file that the user uploads into select options, which works perfectly. I wanted the user to select the name of the parameter and the address and data size would automatically change. This works for the first field sets, but does not work for the field sets that I appended when the more button is pressed. I do not understand why it does not work for the appended part. For example, when I press the add parameter button, and I change the parameter name of the first parameter, it changes the address and size properly. However, when i try to change the appended field set, the address and size do not change.

Comment: You need to use jQuery.on because you remove the select element you bind the initial event to.

Comment: .on also did not work for me??